# Java + PHP Encryption Algorithm Implementation

Tags: java, php, encryption, hash

I'm using [this](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode) site for my salted hashing.

I've got a Java application with the Java implementation of the PBKDF2 encryption system from the above link running fine it generates the hashes and decodes them using the `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` algorithm. I'm trying to duplicate the registration process in PHP using the same algorithm but I can't get it working.

[Reference For Java Algorithm Names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html)

Can someone who understands security more help me change the PHP implementation on the link above so it would work with the `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` algorithm in the Java version?

(If you want me to post source code I can but it's virtually the same as in the link)

What i've tried so far:

1. Changing the hash algorithm in the PHP version to `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` but it throws a `PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.`
2. Changing the Java algorithm to SHA256 but the Java code doesn't seem to match up with the PHP code in any way so it just errors.
3. Looking [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) for the right algorithm, but not finding it.

The overall goal is to let the user register on the website and log into the desktop app. Any pointers would be much appreciated (I would love to provide more details but i'm still learning the security side of things so if you spot any big problems with what i'm trying to do can you explain!)

Comment: I don't see why sha256 won't work it should be the same, the only thing that would throw it off is you mention salting, you would have to salt it the same way for both, a test would be to take exactly what you are hashing ( just prior to ) and hash it with both, the algorithm should be programing language independent.

Comment: As it stands the when i hash using the Java version it produces a much longer string of characters than when I do it with the PHP version, also the PHP version seems to be chopped up using : whereas the Java version isn't

Comment: There are lots of [php+pbkdf2](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+pbkdf2) questions, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961299/pbkdbf2-hash-duplicating-functionality-of-net-rfc2898derivedbytes-class-in-ph) in particular even have a php working code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the php documentation

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php

Here is an efficient PBDKF2 implementation:( 2nd or 3rd down )

Comment: This is a link-only answer. You should provide the relevant explanations and code inside the answer itself.